# How can i prevent a host BSOD when booting a VirtualBox machine?

Tags: virtualbox, bsod, hyper-v, vt-x

Immediately upon starting a VirtualBox Machine on Windows 10, the host OS crashes with a blue screen of death saying 'SYSTEM SERVICE EXCEPTION'. I have Docker for Windows installed and active as well. How can I fix this and boot my VM normally?

Related terms: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION, BSOD, AMD-V, Intel VT-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be happening because VirtualBox is trying to use hardware virtualization while Hyper-V is active. And it just so happens that Docker for Windows enables Hyper-V, as do other tools (such as MS Visual Studio Android emulation). Hyper-V claims/assumes exclusive use of VT-x or ADM-V.

To get your VirtualBox machine running, turn off Hyper-V:

1. Open 'Programs and Features'
2. Click 'Turn Windows features on and
   off'
3. Deselect 'Hyper-V Hypervisor'
4. Confirm and reboot

Of course disabling Hyper-V may cause tools depending on it to lose functionality or stop working altogether.